# What are the system requirements and procedure to build own Blockchain Networks

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I've been working with Hyperledger Fabric, Ethereum, Multichain etc. though when I implement my code I have to host the transaction into any of the networks. Thus, I want to build my own No native currency independent network similar as ethereum networks and Hyperleder. Can anyone recommend the process to create my network, eventually the algorithm will also build blocks and system requirements to do it.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow! Blockchains are large systems; implementing them requires combining many different components, algorithms and architectural choices. 

Because of that, it is not possible to give a definitive answer; it depends on what you want from your network. As such, and please don't feel discouraged by this, I'm going to flag this question as overly broad. I don't think the answers you will get will help you or future travelers.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, consider some more research, and then come back with a more narrow question on this

Comment: This series of articles shows how to implement a simple blockchain system in Go https://jeiwan.cc/posts/building-blockchain-in-go-part-1/